# Java using finalize for child thread shutdown?

Tags: java, multithreading, console-application, finalizer

I am writing a multi-threaded java console application that I am intending to kill via Ctrl-C. In this situation, if I have a class that encapsulates a single thread is it good practice to shutdown the child thread in the encapsulating classes finalize method?

Is it possible to get artifacts of the original application left running if you Ctrl-C the original app and all threads are not shutdown properly?

pseudo code:

```
public class ParentClass {

Thread childThread = new Thread(new ExampleRunnable());

  @Override protected void finalize() throws Throwable {
   childThread.shutdown();
  }
}

public class ExampleRunnable implements Runnable {

 private volatile boolean alive = false;

 @Override
 public void run() {
  alive = true;
  while(alive) {
   //do some work
  }
 }

  public void shutdown() {
   alive = false;
  }
}
```

Comment: There's no guarantee that the finalize method gets executed. Also, note that all the threads are controlled by the JVM, if the JVM turns off, all the threads will die too.

Comment: Sure, but does it hurt to have it and/or is there a situation where it is beneficial?

Comment: In the provided example, it's like adding effort in something that maybe never gets executed.

Comment: So is it safe to assume when the JVM handles the Ctrl-C event that child threads like these will get disposed of properly? When child threads are terminated like this how do I ensure where they terminated at, i.e. finished the last loop of execution. Is there an interrupted exception or something thrown?

Comment: If you need to ensure that code is executed after a `SIGINT` is triggered you should use `Runtime.getRuntime().addShutdownHook()`

Comment: GC of any object with a finalizer takes orders of magnitude longer than it should.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Implementing `finalize` can have a terribly bad side-effect. Way back in the day, Java was slow and one of the reasons was the need to run `finalize` on every object ever created. Now the JVMs are smart enough to check if a non-trivial `finalize` implementation exists rather than blindly call it on every object being collected. Having just one class implement `finalize` may not be bad, but don't make a habit of it.

If you want to do something special during a normal shutdown of the JVM, then use a [shutdown hook](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Runtime.html#addShutdownHook%28java.lang.Thread%29).

Comment: Is it safe if you aren't doing anything special in a particular thread to not explicitly shut it down? Is that pretty standard practice for simple threads?

Comment: Is that frowned upon as bad practice if you don't have a shutdown hook for every thread in your application?

Comment: It depends on what the threads are doing. Most Java programmers I would say use a `ThreadPoolExecutor` rather than `new Thread`. Honestly, I haven't met many people who think about how the application shuts down beyond naturally terminating. Actually, I've worked with people writing services without a framework and they just let the application die without cleanup. I wouldn't call it normal to add a shutdown hook for every Thread. I think the idea is to use shutdown hooks to make sure final actions are taken, like committing data to disk or cleanly closing network connections.

Comment: Thanks for the dialog. I am going to give you the check. The java api seems messy here. It seems strange to have to make another thread and synchronize access to it to shutdown a thread I already have running! Couldn't they just have a method in the runnable interface that acts like a shutdown hook? I see the point in using a ThreadPoolExecutor if you have a lot of short tasks to execute over the life on an application but isn't a single thread simpler when you know it is the only instance throughout?

Comment: You only **need** to do that if the thread in question is doing something important that **requires** orderly shutdown. Otherwise it is perfectly okay to just let the JVM halt it abruptly. Note also that `Thread` is not `final` so you could create a subclass of Thread that registers itself with a statically shared shutdown hook which interrupts and joins each instance of the subclass.